# Jquery replace text but keep case

Tags: jquery, regex, case-sensitive

I am building a website for someone who likes to use the word "Sensasianal" to describe his asian cuisine. The word asian is always picked out using another color which I managed to achieve in Jquery using .replace(), thus:-

```
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/sasiana/ig, "s<em>asian</em>a"));
```

I can then style the  element with a separate color.

However if the original text is uppercase the result is mixed-case.

So I tried this

```
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/SASIANA/ig, "S<em>ASIAN</em>A"));
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/sasiana/ig, "s<em>asian</em>a"));
```

But the result is still mixed-case.

If someone could advise me on how to make the change to the text but retain the original case I would appreciate the assist. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/(s)(asian)(a)/ig, "$1<em>$2</em>$3"));
```

will preserve case, because it reuses the matched text.

Note that `i` is the case insensitivity flag, and `g` means it will match every occurrence, rather than just the first as would happen without the `g` flag.

For a pretty good overview of regular expression functionality in JS, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for this solution and thank you for the explanation. I must admit that regular expressions are a complete mystery to me.

Comment: No worries. The linked MDN article does a pretty good job of explaining them in general, so you may want to give that a read then. Regular expressions are very powerful if you know how to use them.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using [Capturing Groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Capturing_group) in your regex. This will maintain the case of the matched string when creating the output. Here's a working example:

```js
const input = "SENSasianAL";
const output = input.replace(/(S)(ASIAN)(A)/ig, "$1<em>$2</em>$3");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's a shame that I can't choose multiple answers as my accepted answer.

Comment: No worries. Gijs deserves the accept as he gave much more background info than I did.

Comment: Thanks for the gracious comment - I forgot the JS Fiddle, though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/SASIANA/g, "S<em>ASIAN</em>A"));
replaceAsian.html(replaceAsian.html().replace(/sasiana/g, "s<em>asian</em>a"));
```

For additional unformation about regexp see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: I was literally just going to edit my post to say that I didn't understand what the "ig" meant when you answered.

Comment: That's the solution to my problem. Thank you for your help. If you don't mind, could you tell me why this has worked? Does the ig stand for ignore case?

Comment: /i makes the regex match case insensitive.